# Formula for triangle with given side lengths and point inside of it

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry

I have been experimenting a bit with triangles and was wondering what general formulas exist for.

Given a triangle $\triangle ABC$ and a point $M$ inside the triangle. Let the side lengths of the triangle and two of the three connecting distances from one corner to $M$ be given. Is it possible to calculate the third connecting distance $\overline{CM}$, denoted by $x$, without using trigonometry/inverse functions? Does the calculation become easier if the triangle is special in some way, e.g. if $\angle ACB=\angle CBA$ applies?
[image: outline]

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you may be interested to read about trilinear coordinates. I suggest you start with a special case, e.g. an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Any context or any of your attempts towards a solution?

Comment: Using coordinate method one can write equation for $x$, which does not involves trigonometric functions. Or even better: take $A(0,0)$, $B(c,0)$ find $C$ and $M$ coordinates in terms of given lengths, then just calculate $x$ as distance $CM$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Heron-type formula for the volume of a tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Heron-type_formula_for_the_volume_of_a_tetrahedron), which gives the volume of a tetrahedron as a function only of its edges lengths $U$, $V$, $W$, $u$, $v$, $w$:
$$
V = \frac{\sqrt {\,( - p + q + r + s)\,(p - q + r + s)\,(p + q - r + s)\,(p + q + r - s)}}{192\,u\,v\,w}
$$
where
\begin{align}
    p & = \sqrt {xYZ}, & q & = \sqrt {yZX}, & r & = \sqrt {zXY}, & s & = \sqrt {xyz},
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    X & = (w - U + v)\,(U + v + w), & x & = (U - v + w)\,(v - w + U), \\ Y & = (u - V + w)\,(V + w + u), & y & = (V - w + u)\,(w - u + V), \\ Z & = (v - W + u)\,(W + u + v), & z & = (W - u + v)\,(u - v + W).
\end{align}
Here you have a tetrahedron of volume zero, hence one of the factors above the fraction is $0$.  Solving for one edge length should hopefully give two answers, and the smaller is that of interest.

I don't have the courage yet to solve this myself; however there will be no trigonometry involved, I promise.

Comment: I think if $U,V,W$ are the outer triangle sides, then $p+q+r-s=0$.

Comment: @aschepler A wild but symmetric guess would be that one factor vanishes for every vertex that lies in the vector spaces generated by some others. Then there would be only one factor which vanishes here.